# The site in the encoded share URI is invalid

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I've tried to use Microsoft Graph to pull some files from a shared link. However, when I try to do that using the Microsoft Graph Explorer, it returns:

```
"error": {
   "code": "invalidRequest",
   "message": "The site in the encoded share URI is invalid.",
   "innerError": {
       "request-id": "e07b0df4-88e0-49fd-97e4-eccaaf887d6e",
       "date": "2019-11-29T19:05:52"
    }
}
```

The encoding code is this(same as on the docs):

```cs
string base64Value =
  Convert
  .ToBase64String(UTF8
        .GetBytes("https://1drv.ms/f/s!An8UzxYP03zbg5lyUW0nVFclockIaw"));

string encodedUrl = "u!" + 
   base64Value.TrimEnd('=')
  .Replace('/', '_')
  .Replace('+', '-');
```

The link is in the code and goes to an empty shared folder (for testing purposes).

Comment: I don't follow what you're attempting to do here. How are you sending this URI to Microsoft Graph and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Soo, a couple of months have passed and I have managed to fix my problem:

How did I do it?

TLDR: The share URI isn't extracted as MS tells you (for whatever reason)

Let's take my example folder:

```
https://1drv.ms/f/s!An8UzxYP03zbg5lyUW0nVFclockIaw
```

In this case, the URI is everything after(including)the "s" part, so in my case it's `s!An8UzxYP03zbg5lyUW0nVFclockIaw`

**CODE**

```
    private static string GetIDFromLink(string website)
    {
        return "s!" + website.TrimStart("https://1drv.ms/f/".ToCharArray());
    }
```

**Don't forget that you MUST be logged in to MSGraph and have the proper permission to access files**
Also, if you're using the "Application Daemon" method(aka, no user sign-in) you must have a SharePoint 365 subscription active(at least from what I've observed, I would like to be wrong on that)

Comment: I have the same problem with my link, the solution provided here doesn't work: https://1drv.ms/w/s!Apb0GUJt7b5wbaxZ8zBORpDY708

Comment: I get the same error, but the share link I'm trying to decode (to a DriveItem) is formatted like this, published format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/shorter-share-link-format I have tried just using pieces or encoding the whole URL as documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online but neither works

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, turned out i wasn't logged into graph under my account

derp.