# Microsoft Graph API: Download OneDrive shared link

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, outlook-restapi

I sent an email with an OneDrive reference type attachment. 
Now I want to download it by the Microsoft Graph API. Here I get an attachment object
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/xxx/attachments`

with a SourceUrl:
`https://1drv.ms/w/s!Apb0GUJt7b5wbaxZ8zBORpDY708`

When I'm trying to download it from the OneDrive:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/shares/s!Apb0GUJt7b5wbaxZ8zBORpDY708`
I get this error:
*"The provided share id was malformed"*

and when I base64 encode the entire SourceUrl:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3cvcyFBcGIwR1VKdDdiNXdiYXhaOHpCT1JwRFk3MDg`
I get this error:
*"The site in the encoded share URI is invalid"*

The solution provided here doesn't work:
[The site in the encoded share URI is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109993/the-site-in-the-encoded-share-uri-is-invalid)

Comment: I've tried to recreate the situation using MS's graph explorer and `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/shares/s!Apb0GUJt7b5wbaxZ8zBORpDY708` works just fine. As stated in that question by another user, make sure you are logged in before trying to access the files and also make sure that you have the right permissions set for you program. If this still doesn't work, then test the link with MS Graph's explorer while logged in with your account. If this doesn't work either, you should update this post with the code and somebody will probably be able to give you a hand.

Comment: The original URL `https://1drv.ms/w/s!Apb0GUJt7b5wbaxZ8zBORpDY708` is public that previews the file without any login. If there is a required login it is a bug and shouldn't happen.

Comment: Login is required, no matter what kind of link it is.

Comment: Why it is required? If so, it is a bug in a Microsoft side.

Comment: Probably because they want to make sure that bots don't spam the system, I'm not sure, you'd better off ask MS about that.