# MS Graph API returns "The site in the encoded share URI is invalid." for apparently valid URI for a shared file

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm referring to this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/shares_get?view=odsp-graph-online on how to encode URIs for use with MS Graph API accessing shares.

My test URL which is a publicly shared file and seems to work fine, even if not logged in, is: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Alwuj_GU-JiCgYEI-kYrrTjyHUStlw?e=lgkUYX

Then the described process is to base64 encode the URI and then perform some character replacements and a prefix, this gives:

Base64 encoded:

```
aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3gvcyFBbHd1al9HVS1KaUNnWUVJLWtZcnJUanlIVVN0bHc/ZT1sZ2tVWVg=
```

After char replacements and prefix:

```
u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3gvcyFBbHd1al9HVS1KaUNnWUVJLWtZcnJUanlIVVN0bHc_ZT1sZ2tVWVg
```

That should then mean this URI should fetch the document details:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!aHR0cHM6Ly8xZHJ2Lm1zL3gvcyFBbHd1al9HVS1KaUNnWUVJLWtZcnJUanlIVVN0bHc_ZT1sZ2tVWVg/driveItem

But the response is (EDIT):

```
"code": "invalidRequest",
"message": "The site in the encoded share URI is invalid.",
"innerError": {
     "date": "2020-12-09T11:44:29",
     "request-id": "305c6344-d59f-481b-9d28-334d72bd8ab0",
     "client-request-id": "66138690-8312-a6d7-b35f-97bee7c32523"
}
```

It gets the same both when running on the Graph Explorer (logged in) and from our application itself.

What am I doing wrong? Have tried a lot of variations on the above, can't find anything that works.

Comment: Dan, can you share the requestid, timestamp of the above error. Also have you looked at the [older thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109993/the-site-in-the-encoded-share-uri-is-invalid)?

Comment: Sure, have just edited and added. (This is from an attempt with the Graph Explorer, which anyone should be able to replicate as the file is publicly accessible). The older thread seemed a bit inconclusive/unclear and I got "malformed URL" errors when trying it. In any case, if the documentation was as wrong as suggested there it needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Dev did you see I had entered the request ID and timestamp in the post?